# ImportError: cannot import name 'Collection'

Tags: python-3.x

While trying :

```
from typing import Collection
```

I get :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Collection'
```

In python 3.5 .

Comment: [`typing.Collection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Collection) is new in Python 3.6

Comment: Ok , thanks for the answer